# Table name can be any email in php?

Tags: php

**I want table name is email like **

```
<?php
$email="eamil@gmail.com" 

$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $email(
                id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                date VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                time VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                )";
?>
```

**error**
check the manual that corresponds to your ***MariaDB*** server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com

Comment: **Such a BAD Idea**

Comment: Please take a few hours and read a few chapters of a Relational Database design book

Comment: Follow Naming Rules [Click here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/naming-rules/)

Comment: Not enough code and there is already a parse error

Comment: It's Always Appreciable To Think Differently. But, My Friend, Don't Ever Think To Implement Such Concepts. *Spend A Week, Gather Few Informations Related To RDBMS*

Comment: Thanks sir for yours answers.....

Comment: better not store date and time separately and not in a varchar type column: DATETIME makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "backticks" (`) in order to quote the table name.

See [Identifier Names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/identifier-names/) (e.g. the example *Creating a table with characters that require quoting*).

```
<?php
$email="eamil@gmail.com";

$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $email . "`(
                id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                date VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                time VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                )";
?>
```

P.S: Try to avoid such a solution, even if it works. Keep your identifiers (db names, table names, column names) clean from special characters, spaces, etc.

Semicolon at the end of the first variable assignment was missing too, as @Fred-ii- kindly pointed out.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution for the question asked. However: the question comes from a bad idea. You can expect TS wants to add tables like email@hotmail.com, email@yahoo.com etc.  Better he would have one table named "emails" or whatever, and add one column to the list id, date, time: email. In that field he would place the email address to separeate data.

Comment: @IvoP You all have of course right, at first sight. Though is not bad design to use "first_dev" as database name, isn't it? It contains a char which needs quoting/escaping (as I recall)... Yes, the bad design in OP's question comes from the logical arrangement thought by Arslan and corrected by you and the others, not from the table name per se. I showed him just how to do quoting and you gave him already the right advices about the design. So, now he learned two things. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: there contains the same parse error created by the OP here

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii-. But could you please tell me what do you mean? I ran the code and it works fine.

Comment: @aendeerei `$email="eamil@gmail.com"` the missing closure will throw a parse error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, indeed :-) Thanks.